# Matrix normalization to use multicriteria methods

Tags: r, multicriteria-decision-analysis

I'm using the TOPSIS and VIKOR multicriteria methods to generate rankings according to the decision matrix that I call a `database`. I would like to know if the normalized decision matrix is already embedded in the `TOPSIS` and `VIKOR` function, since the results are generated from the normalized decision matrix. Can anyone tell me something about this? So are my results correct that way or would I need to normalize my `database` decision matrix first?

```
library(topsis)
library(MCDM)

database <- structure(c(790.07529753148, 987.560758390604, 1717.41117836404, 
1257.03757052034, 1155.65871783395, 1114.47680404529, 965.589449089402, 
860.041671387026, 774.152044283882, 570.169757216762, 563.787227344011, 
1254.976476, 1216.074832, 315.114268, 295.3384, 295.3384, 229.824, 
229.824, 229.824, 229.310304, 229.310304, 29.856976), .Dim = c(11L, 
2L),.Dimnames = list(NULL, c("C1", "C2")))

> database
             C1         C2
 [1,]  790.0753 1254.97648
 [2,]  987.5608 1216.07483
 [3,] 1717.4112  315.11427
 [4,] 1257.0376  295.33840
 [5,] 1155.6587  295.33840
 [6,] 1114.4768  229.82400
 [7,]  965.5894  229.82400
 [8,]  860.0417  229.82400
 [9,]  774.1520  229.31030
[10,]  570.1698  229.31030
[11,]  563.7872   29.85698
```

**TOPSIS**

```
w <- c(0.5,0.5) 
i <- c("-", "+") 
result1<-topsis(database, w, i)

> result1
   alt.row     score rank
1        1 0.9135330    1
2        2 0.8400032    2
3        3 0.2004466   11
4        4 0.2628604   10
5        5 0.2877750    8
6        6 0.2673059    9
7        7 0.3063391    7
8        8 0.3323752    6
9        9 0.3521251    4
10      10 0.3945119    3
11      11 0.3436264    5
```

**VIKOR**

```
  w <- c(0.5,0.5)
  cb <- c('min','max')
  v <- 0.5
  result2<-VIKOR(database,w,cb,v)

> result2
   Alternatives          S          R         Q Ranking
1             1 0.09807705 0.09807705 0.0000000       1
2             2 0.19954724 0.18367057 0.1710693       2
3             3 0.88357981 0.50000000 1.0000000      11
4             4 0.69211715 0.39165080 0.7433388       8
5             5 0.64817785 0.39165080 0.7153699       7
6             6 0.65706688 0.41838877 0.7542906       9
7             7 0.59253660 0.41838877 0.7132148       6
8             8 0.54679042 0.41838877 0.6840958       5
9             9 0.50977406 0.41859842 0.6607944       4
10           10 0.42136471 0.41859842 0.6045188       3
11           11 0.50000000 0.50000000 0.7558380      10
```